# Из Delphi(forms) в Delphi(win32 API)

Tags: delphi

Есть довольно простой код на Delphi7 с использованием стандартных форм. Надо перевести этот код в Win32 API без использования стандартных библиотек и форм.(Может я не так как-то выразилась). Подскажите как это делается. Или если это все быстро то можете написать.

```
unit RGB;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ScrollBar1: TScrollBar;
    ScrollBar2: TScrollBar;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    ScrollBar3: TScrollBar;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ScrollBar1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ScrollBar2Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ScrollBar3Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
    procedure Edit2KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
    procedure Edit3KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function RGBToColor(R, G, B: Byte): TColor;
begin
  Result := B shl 16 or G shl 8 or R;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ScrollBar1.Position:=StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
    ScrollBar2.Position:=StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
    ScrollBar3.Position:=StrToInt(Edit3.Text);

    Panel1.Color:=RGBToColor(ScrollBar1.Position, ScrollBar2.Position, ScrollBar3.Position);
end;

procedure TForm1.ScrollBar1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Edit1.Text:=IntToStr(ScrollBar1.Position);
    Panel1.Color:=RGBToColor(ScrollBar1.Position, ScrollBar2.Position, ScrollBar3.Position);
end;

procedure TForm1.ScrollBar2Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Edit2.Text:=IntToStr(ScrollBar2.Position);
    Panel1.Color:=RGBToColor(ScrollBar1.Position, ScrollBar2.Position, ScrollBar3.Position);
end;

procedure TForm1.ScrollBar3Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Edit3.Text:=IntToStr(ScrollBar3.Position);
    Panel1.Color:=RGBToColor(ScrollBar1.Position, ScrollBar2.Position, ScrollBar3.Position);
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
    case Key of
        '0'..'9': ; // цифра
        #8 : ; // клавиша <Back Space>
        #13 : Edit2.SetFocus ; // клавиша <Enter>, переводим фокус на второй Edit
        // остальные символы — запрещены
    else Key :=Chr(0);
    end;
    if (Edit1.Text<>'') then
        ScrollBar1.Position:=StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
    Panel1.Color:=RGBToColor(ScrollBar1.Position, ScrollBar2.Position, ScrollBar3.Position);
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit2KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
    case Key of
        '0'..'9': ; // цифра
        #8 : ; // клавиша <Back Space>
        #13 : Edit3.SetFocus ; // клавиша <Enter>, переводим фокус на второй Edit
        // остальные символы — запрещены
    else Key :=Chr(0);
    end;
    if (Edit2.Text<>'') then
        ScrollBar2.Position:=StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
    Panel1.Color:=RGBToColor(ScrollBar1.Position, ScrollBar2.Position, ScrollBar3.Position);
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit3KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
   case Key of
        '0'..'9': ; // цифра
        #8 : ; // клавиша <Back Space>
        #13 : Edit1.SetFocus ; // клавиша <Enter>, переводим фокус на второй Edit
        // остальные символы — запрещены
    else Key :=Chr(0);
    end;
    if (Edit3.Text<>'') then
        ScrollBar3.Position:=StrToInt(Edit3.Text);
    Panel1.Color:=RGBToColor(ScrollBar1.Position, ScrollBar2.Position, ScrollBar3.Position);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Без форм вам будет очень-очень-очень сложно, учитывая ваш уровень. Вам это точно надо?

Comment: К сожалению такое задание...

Comment: Вот продвинулась немного, пока застряла на этом моменте

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1349465/Как-добавить-элемент-scrollbar-win32-api-delphi7

Answer (score 0):

Создать окно с помощью `CreateWindow(Ex)`, обрабатывать сообщения внутри оконной функции.

[Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180016/creating-forms-without-using-vcl) с созданием дочерних элементов.

Comment: А как правильно запустить? есть по шагам инструкция?

Comment: Записать код в .dpr файл и скомпилировать.