# Как добавить элемент scrollbar win32 API Delphi7

Tags: pascal, delphi-7

Как добавить элемент scrollbar win32 API Delphi7. Мне необходимо добавить три scrollbar min=0 max=255 у каждого. И чтоб при передвижении ползунка менялись значения в соответствующих edit
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
program Project1;

uses
  Windows,
  Messages,
  SysUtils;

var
  Msg        : TMSG;
  LWndClass  : TWndClass;
  hMainHandle: HWND;
  hButton    : HWND;
  hStatic    : HWND;
  hEdit      : HWND;
  hEdit1     : HWND;
  hEdit2     : HWND;
  hFontText  : HWND;
  hFontButton: HWND;

procedure ReleaseResources;
begin
  DestroyWindow(hButton);
  DestroyWindow(hStatic);
  DestroyWindow(hEdit);
  DestroyWindow(hEdit1);
  DestroyWindow(hEdit2);
  DeleteObject(hFontText);
  DeleteObject(hFontButton);
  PostQuitMessage(0);
end;

function SetScrollRange(hWnd: HWND; nBar, nMinPos, nMaxPos: Integer;
bRedraw: BOOL): BOOL;
 begin
 end;
function WindowProc(hWnd,Msg:Longint; wParam : WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM):Longint; stdcall;
begin
  case Msg of
      WM_COMMAND: if lParam = hButton then
                    MessageBox(hMainHandle,'You pressed the button Hello', 'Hello',MB_OK or MB_ICONINFORMATION);
      WM_DESTROY: ReleaseResources;
  end;
  Result:=DefWindowProc(hWnd,Msg,wParam,lParam);
end;

begin
  //create the window
  LWndClass.hInstance := hInstance;
  with LWndClass do
    begin
      lpszClassName := 'MyWinApiWnd';
      Style         := CS_PARENTDC or CS_BYTEALIGNCLIENT;
      hIcon         := LoadIcon(hInstance,'MAINICON');
      lpfnWndProc   := @WindowProc;
      hbrBackground := COLOR_BTNFACE+1;
      hCursor       := LoadCursor(0,IDC_ARROW);
    end;

  RegisterClass(LWndClass);
  hMainHandle := CreateWindow(LWndClass.lpszClassName,'RGB', WS_CAPTION or WS_MINIMIZEBOX or WS_SYSMENU or WS_VISIBLE, (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) div 2)-190,
      (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) div 2)-170, 386,200,0,0,hInstance,nil);

  //Create the fonts to use
  hFontText := CreateFont(-14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,DEFAULT_CHARSET,OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,DEFAULT_QUALITY,VARIABLE_PITCH or FF_SWISS,'Tahoma');
  hFontButton := CreateFont(-14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,DEFAULT_CHARSET,OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,DEFAULT_QUALITY,VARIABLE_PITCH or FF_SWISS,'Tahoma');

  //create the edit
  hEdit:=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,'Edit','0', WS_VISIBLE or WS_CHILD or ES_LEFT or ES_AUTOHSCROLL,200,35,160,23,hMainHandle,0,hInstance,nil);
  hEdit1:=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,'Edit','0', WS_VISIBLE or WS_CHILD or ES_LEFT or ES_AUTOHSCROLL,200,65,160,23,hMainHandle,0,hInstance,nil);
  hEdit2:=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,'Edit','0', WS_VISIBLE or WS_CHILD or ES_LEFT or ES_AUTOHSCROLL,200,95,160,23,hMainHandle,0,hInstance,nil);

  SendMessage(hEdit,WM_SETFONT,hFontText,0);
  SendMessage(hEdit1,WM_SETFONT,hFontText,0);
  SendMessage(hEdit2,WM_SETFONT,hFontText,0);



end.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
program Project1;

uses
  Windows,
  Messages,
  SysUtils;

var
  Msg        : TMSG;
  LWndClass  : TWndClass;
  hMainHandle: HWND;
  hButton    : HWND;
  hStatic    : HWND;
  hEdit      : HWND;
  hEdit1     : HWND;
  hEdit2     : HWND;
  hFontText  : HWND;
  hFontButton: HWND;
  hScroll    : HWND;
  hScroll1    : HWND;
  hScroll2    : HWND;

procedure ReleaseResources;
begin
  DestroyWindow(hButton);
  DestroyWindow(hStatic);
  DestroyWindow(hEdit);
  DestroyWindow(hEdit1);
  DestroyWindow(hEdit2);
  DestroyWindow(hScroll);
  DestroyWindow(hScroll1);
  DestroyWindow(hScroll2);
  DeleteObject(hFontText);
  DeleteObject(hFontButton);
  PostQuitMessage(0);
end;

function SetScrollRange(hWnd: HWND; nBar, nMinPos, nMaxPos: Integer;
bRedraw: BOOL): BOOL;
 begin
     Result:=true;
 end;
function WindowProc(hWnd,Msg:Longint; wParam : WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM):Longint; stdcall;
begin
  case Msg of
      WM_DESTROY: ReleaseResources;
  end;
  Result:=DefWindowProc(hWnd,Msg,wParam,lParam);
end;

begin
  //create the window
  LWndClass.hInstance := hInstance;
  with LWndClass do
    begin
      lpszClassName := 'MyWinApiWnd';
      Style         := CS_PARENTDC or CS_BYTEALIGNCLIENT;
      hIcon         := LoadIcon(hInstance,'MAINICON');
      lpfnWndProc   := @WindowProc;
      hbrBackground := 14;
      hCursor       := LoadCursor(0,IDC_ARROW);
    end;

  RegisterClass(LWndClass);
  hMainHandle := CreateWindow(LWndClass.lpszClassName,'RGB', WS_CAPTION or WS_MINIMIZEBOX or WS_SYSMENU or WS_VISIBLE, (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) div 2)-190,
      (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) div 2)-170, 386,200,0,0,hInstance,nil);

  //Create the fonts to use
  hFontText := CreateFont(-14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,DEFAULT_CHARSET,OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,DEFAULT_QUALITY,VARIABLE_PITCH or FF_SWISS,'Tahoma');
  hFontButton := CreateFont(-14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,DEFAULT_CHARSET,OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,DEFAULT_QUALITY,VARIABLE_PITCH or FF_SWISS,'Tahoma');

  //create the edit
  hEdit:=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,'Edit','0', WS_VISIBLE or WS_CHILD or ES_LEFT or ES_AUTOHSCROLL,200,35,160,23,hMainHandle,0,hInstance,nil);
  hEdit1:=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,'Edit','0', WS_VISIBLE or WS_CHILD or ES_LEFT or ES_AUTOHSCROLL,200,65,160,23,hMainHandle,0,hInstance,nil);
  hEdit2:=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,'Edit','0', WS_VISIBLE or WS_CHILD or ES_LEFT or ES_AUTOHSCROLL,200,95,160,23,hMainHandle,0,hInstance,nil);

  SendMessage(hEdit,WM_SETFONT,hFontText,0);
  SendMessage(hEdit1,WM_SETFONT,hFontText,0);
  SendMessage(hEdit2,WM_SETFONT,hFontText,0);

  hScroll:=CreateWindowEx(WM_HSCROLL, 'Scrollbar','0', WS_VISIBLE or WS_CHILD or ES_LEFT or ES_AUTOHSCROLL,10,35,160,23,hMainHandle,0,hInstance,nil);
  hScroll1:=CreateWindowEx(WM_HSCROLL, 'Scrollbar','0', WS_VISIBLE or WS_CHILD or ES_LEFT or ES_AUTOHSCROLL,10,65,160,23,hMainHandle,0,hInstance,nil);
  hScroll2:=CreateWindowEx(WM_HSCROLL, 'Scrollbar','0', WS_VISIBLE or WS_CHILD or ES_LEFT or ES_AUTOHSCROLL,10,95,160,23,hMainHandle,0,hInstance,nil);
  SetScrollRange(hScroll,SB_HORZ,0,255,true);



  SendMessage(hScroll,WM_SETFONT,hFontText,0);
  SendMessage(hScroll1,WM_SETFONT,hFontText,0);
  SendMessage(hScroll2,WM_SETFONT,hFontText,0);


  //message loop
  while GetMessage(Msg,0,0,0) do
  begin
    TranslateMessage(Msg);
    DispatchMessage(Msg);
  end;

end.
```

Comment: Я добавила 3 scrollbar как теперь выставить в них максимальное и минимальное значение, установить взаимосвязь с edit

Comment: А что значит ваш комментарий, и почему вы не добавили его в текст ответа?

Comment: Это то что мне необходимо еще сделать в этом задание и то что я не знаю как делать...

Comment: В общем надо сделать три полосы прокрутки, меняя значение ползунка менялись соответствующие цифры в edit, а затем и менялся фон

Comment: Вы дали ответ, это значит, что  ваш вопрос решён. На ответ вам никто не ответит. Поэтому, задайте новый вопрос и сошлитесь в нём на текущий.